# Append String Value To Int Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query just a simple Select Statement, how can I append (from within the query) a value to my int column?  I have tried the below, but keep getting this error:
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Syntax error converting the varchar value 'Month ' to a column of data type int.

```
SELECT a.Sales, SUM(a.Count) As Count, CONVERT(INT, 'Month ') + dt.CumulativeMonth
FROM Rep a
INNER JOIN Date dt
ON a.Date = dt.FD
GROUP BY dt.CumulativeMonth, a.Sales
```

Comment: Addition / math has priority over string concatenation. To make it clear to SQL Server that you want to join strings, not add, you should convert the month to a string, e.g. `CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), dt.CumulativeMonth)`. Not sure why you are trying to convert `'Month '` to an integer. How does that work exactly?

Comment: I just want to append the text Month to the beginning of a numeric month value.  I can't modify the table so thought I would just do it from within the Select statement.

Comment: @Shiva yes, apology for my mistake there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
SELECT a.Sales, SUM(a.Count) As Count, 'Month ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), dt.CumulativeMonth)
FROM Rep a
INNER JOIN Date dt
ON a.Date = dt.FD
GROUP BY dt.CumulativeMonth, a.Sales
```